# Asp.net core from a controller return html as a string or json to a ajax call

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, asp.net-ajax, asp.net-mvc-partialview

I'm making a Ajax call to action method which should return Html elements as a string or json. Html should generate using a partialview and model. Please guide me how to acheive it
Example:something like this

return View("_PartialView", model);

or

```
return ok("_PartialView", model);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Able to achieve it using PartialView

Example:

```
return PartialView("_PartialView", model);
```

Comment: So,you have resolved your issue by using return PartialView("_PartialView",model)?

Comment: @Rena 

Yes, resolved. I'm able to append returned data to a div.

Comment: Yes, I tried that. But it seems I need to wait at least 48 hours. In the link which you shared, under section "Can I accept my own self-answer?" there is a point as "The question must be at least 48 hours old before you can accept a self-answer."